# Heading of Turtles to embedded Patches

Tags: netlogo, patch, heading

Determine heading of Patch to Turtle Embedded in Procedures

I'm trying to get the heading from the current turtle (which called this procedure) to the patch (called in this procedure by the ask patch-ahead procedure), but Netlogo returns the error:

> expected a closing parenthesis here

What's the issue here?

```
while [i <= 3] [
    ask patch-ahead i [
      show pcolor
      ask myself [set h (heading [heading] of patch self)]
      set m lput pcolor m
      set m lput h  m
      set m lput i m
      ask myself [set PA_Perceive_Visual-Scan lput m PA_Perceive_Visual-Scan]
      if ((pcolor = green) or (pcolor = grey)) [ (set i 11) ]
     ]
```

I just need the heading from the turtle to the patch being called.

Comment: Which line is the error message referring to? The word "here" in the message provides diagnostic information you have omitted.

Comment: I cleaned up the code to highlight the problem:

Comment: let i 0 
let h 0

ask turtle 1 [
  while [i <= 3] [
    ask patch-ahead i [
      set h (heading towards self)
    ]
  set i (i + 1)
  ]
]

Comment: Sorry, that looks terrible...I thought it would keep the code as formatted when I pasted it in.

Comment: Anyways...what I am trying to do is simulate visual scanning of AAs within NetLogo. So a Turtle looks at the patch in front of it (or to the side) and determines the heading (and distance) to that patch...but without using x,y coordinates. In the case of patch-ahead, the result is trivial (0 deg), but once I scan forward-left or forward-right, the heading will move off of 0 deg.

Comment: So back to your question...the error highlights (in the new code that I pasted in) the word "towards".

Comment: I solved my own problem...code is as follows:

ask turtle 1 [
  while [i <= 3] [
     ask patch-ahead i [
        set h (towards myself)
     ]
  set i (i + 1)
  ]
]

Comment: On SO comments should not be used to "improve" the question (as you have found for example, posting code is not pretty - though there is limited `code markup` you could have used).  Edit the question instead to add or update the information.